# Compute combinations of 1 & 2 from master list

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations, combinatorics

We start with a set of n elements, all unique. We then need to compute all possible combinations such that:

1. We allow sets of 1 & 2 elements from the parent set
2. Each element from the original set shows exactly once

Example#1, master set of 4 unique elements: `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

```
[[1], [2], [3], [4]]
[[1], [2], [3, 4]]
[[1], [2, 4], [3]]
[[1], [2, 3], [4]]
[[1, 4], [2], [3]]
[[1, 3], [2], [4]]
[[1, 2], [3], [4]]
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
[[1, 3], [2, 4]]
[[1, 4], [2, 3]]
```

Example#2, a set of 5: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Results:

```
[[1], [2], [3], [4, 5]]
[[1], [2], [3, 5], [4]]
[[1], [2], [3, 4], [5]]
[[1], [2, 5], [3], [4]]
[[1], [2, 4], [3], [5]]
[[1], [2, 3], [4], [5]]
[[1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]
[[1], [2, 4], [3, 5]]
[[1], [2, 5], [3, 4]]
[[1, 5], [2], [3], [4]]
[[1, 4], [2], [3], [5]]
[[1, 3], [2], [4], [5]]
[[1, 3], [2], [4, 5]]
[[1, 4], [2], [3, 5]]
[[1, 5], [2], [3, 4]]
[[1, 2], [3], [4], [5]]
[[1, 2], [3], [4, 5]]
[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3]]
[[1, 5], [2, 4], [3]]
[[1, 2], [3, 5], [4]]
[[1, 3], [2, 5], [4]]
[[1, 5], [2, 3], [4]]
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5]]
[[1, 3], [2, 4], [5]]
[[1, 4], [2, 3], [5]]
```

The real world significance behind this problem:

1. Each of those elements in the set is actually a customer drop point for delivery
2. We can choose to combine drop points with 1 delivery partner i.e. 1 delivery partner can deliver 2 orders
3. We choose to limit the number of drops per delivery partner to 2 (hence the limit on combinations of sets of 2)
4. All the drop points should get covered when deciding which delivery partner takes what (hence the condition that each element should be covered exactly once)
5. We then generate all possible combinations - and then get the cost of each configuration and then assign the delivery partners where cost is lowest

Answer (score 0):

Not the most optimal solution, plenty of room for improvements, but should do the trick. For a given `parent_set` generate all possible 1 and 2 element subsets and iterate through all of them. Each iteration, remove the elements present in the current subset from the parent set and repeat recursively. This approach, however, produces repetitions as `{(1), (2))` and `{(2), (1)}` are considered two distinct solutions. Converting all results into a set gets rid of those repetitions.

```py
import itertools


def find_combinations_impl(parent_set):
  subsets = itertools.chain(
    itertools.combinations(parent_set, 1),
    itertools.combinations(parent_set, 2)
  )
  for subset in subsets:
    remaining = parent_set - set(subset)
    element = frozenset({subset})
    if remaining:
      yield from map(element.union, find_combinations_impl(remaining))
    else:
      yield element


def find_combinations(parent_set):
  return set(find_combinations_impl(set(parent_set)))
```